# How to combine array inside foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

I have this nested array

```
$lists = [
  [
   {"id": 1, "name": one},
   {"id": 2, "name": two},
   {"id": 3, "name": three},
  ],
  [
   {"id": 4, "name": four},
   {"id": 5, "name": five},
   {"id": 6, "name": six},
  ]
]
```

What should i do to make this array into one like this.

```
[
   {"id": 1, "name": one},
   {"id": 2, "name": two},
   {"id": 3, "name": three},
   {"id": 4, "name": four},
   {"id": 5, "name": five},
   {"id": 6, "name": six},
]
```

I tried array_merge using this code

```
$numbers =[];
foreach ($lists as $list) {
    $numbers = array_merge($numbers, $list);
}
```

But it didn't work. It says that argument #2 is not an array.

Comment: Where's the index `numbers` you're referring to? I can't see it in the arrays you've posted? You should also clarify what "didn't work" means. Wrong result? Errors?

Comment: the numbers index consist the array in the first code. Sorry forgot to add

Comment: `json_encode(array_merge(...json_decode($json, true)))`-  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6de77f9aaf738b3a11c4235bf0db71dcf5135469

Comment: question edited, please see and mybe it can help you identify my problem

Comment: `$lists` is invalid.

Comment: what do you mean by invalid ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-mapinto

Comment: It's invalid since you can't define arrays/objects like that in PHP. That's json, not PHP-notation. The `$lists`-definition should throw syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can try this way. I hope it will be helpful**

```
$lists =array(
 array(
    array("id"=> 1, "name"=> "one"),
    array("id"=> 2, "name"=> "two"),
    array("id"=> 3, "name"=> "three")
  ),
  array(
    array("id"=> 4, "name"=> "four"),
    array("id"=> 5, "name"=> "five"),
    array("id"=> 6, "name"=> "six")

  )
);

    $numbers =array();
foreach ($lists as $list) {

   foreach ($list as $c) {
    array_push($numbers,$c);
   }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($numbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues.  The initial data is invalid JSON, but this is an aside, I've fixed it in the data below.

You are looping over an empty array `$lists` which you create just before the loop.  Here I've created this from the JSON data and removed the array initialisation.  Lastly you where using `$list['numbers']` where `numbers` isn't defined anywhere ...

```
$json = '[
  [
   {"id": 1, "name": "one"},
   {"id": 2, "name": "two"},
   {"id": 3, "name": "three"}
  ],
  [
   {"id": 4, "name": "four"},
   {"id": 5, "name": "five"},
   {"id": 6, "name": "six"}
  ]
]';

$lists = json_decode($json, true);
$numbers =[];
foreach ($lists as $list) {
    $numbers = array_merge($numbers, $list);
}
print_r($numbers);
```

Update:

As a guess to what you've added in the comments to the question, try...

```
$numbers =[];
foreach ($lists['numbers'] as $list) {
    $numbers = array_merge($numbers, $list);
}
print_r($numbers);
```

Comment: When I used array_merge, it says that the argument #2 is not an array.

Comment: How do you convert your data (I've used `json_decode()`) to the data you want to use.  I can't test it if I don't have your original data.

Comment: I've added a new piece of code, this may be what your asking for but it isn't clear.

Comment: question edited, please see and mybe it can help you identify my problem

Comment: @MONSTER The $lists is not a corrcet php array, meybe it's an output from APi or dumping something in your controller. please be sure what is $lists type

Comment: Thanks for the idea of json_decode sir @NigelRen. got an idea. :)